# Print out a single character from a character string in C

Tags: c

My problem is that I only want to do a simple test for printing out a single character from a char. My code looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char table[20] = "Hello";

    printf("%s \n", table[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I only get segementation fault, and I have also tried with curly brackets ({})

Comment: printf("%c \n", table[0]);

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. At least use '-Wall' when compiling. That should give you a warning, which is almost always better than getting a segfault.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%c` to do that.

```
printf("%c", table[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` format specifier expects an address to a (null terminated) string. Instead, your code passes just the ASCII value of the letter 'H' (72 in decimal) which is of course not a valid address of any string.

To print the first character:

```
printf("%c\n", table[0]);
```

To print the whole string:

```
printf("%s\n", table);
```

Answer (score 2):

You neeed to use `%c` instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using %c instead of %s. %s will try to print the whole string, which is not null-terminated since it was initialized as an array of characters. Without the null-termination at the end of the string, %s runs off the end and gives you a seg-fault.

Comment: This is not correct. Using `%c` instead of `%s` is correct but the explanation is wrong. The code will not try to print the whole string. It will take `H` as a pointer to a string and then seg-fault. Compiler warnings should have shown this.

Comment: "which is not null-terminated since it was initialized as an array of characters." Wrong. when a char array is initialized with a string literal, it is null terminated, unless it has exactly the same size as the number of characters in the string.